# How to render all child elements when there is a change in array of items using *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I have  array of items.

```
items = [{id: 0, visible: true, height:56, width: 67 }, 
         {id: 1, visible: true, height:56, width: 67 }, 
         {id: 2, visible: true, height:56, width: 67 }, 
         {id: 3, visible: true, height:56, width: 67} ]
```

After this , when the array is changed to

```
items = [{id: 0, visible: true,  height:102, width: 67 }, 
         {id: 1, visible: true,  height:102, width: 67 }, 
         {id: 2, visible: false, height:56,  width: 67 }, 
         {id: 3, visible: false, height:56,  width: 67} ]
```

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <child [item]="item"></child>
</div>
```

```
items$: Observable<Item[]>;
items: Item[];

this.items$ = this.store.select(state => state.items);

this.items$.subscribe(
    items => {
        if (items.length > 0) {
            this.items = items.filter(x => x.visible === true);
        }
     },
     error => {
         console.log('error', error);
     }
);
```

Expected: 
items[0], items[1] needs to be visible and div height width must change to new values. items[2], items[3] need to be removed from dom.

Actual:
items[0], items[1] are  visible. but div height , width are not changing.

Comment: Can you show us the code for your `child.component`?

Answer (score -1):

this.items = items.filter(x=>x.visible); You have two semicolons unsure if that's it.

You aren't setting any style from what I see. You just pass the item into a child component which I assume sets the style?

Comment: Two semicolons wouldn't cause a problem.